# How to create random binary/boolean variable in Netlogo

Tags: random, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I'd like to assign a random boolean variable to each turtle, but I'm not seeing a function that would simulate a draw from a Bernoulli distribution.

This gets close, but it's awkward:

```
ifelse random-in-range 0 1 < .5 [set expensive? false]
[ set expensive? true ]
```

Anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few options:

- `one-of [ true false ]`
- `random 2 = 1`
- `random-float 1 < 0.5` - If you need to modify the probability, to get any Bernoulli distribution you want

If I deal with a lot of probabilistic stuff in a model, I like to add

```
to-report probability [ p ]
  report random-float 1 < p
end
```

as an easy shorthand.

Also, note that the `ifelse` is redundant in your code. You can just do `set expensive? one-of [ true false ]` or whichever is your preferred method.