# How do I assign a gender randomly to turtle breeds in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

For an assignment in one of my classes we need to model disease spread and also have the turtles, whether sick or healthy, reproduce when a male and a female end up on the same patch, and it's also based on a slider with probability of reproduction. We're supposed to have the gender assigned randomly at birth so that the reproduction works properly. Any idea how to do this?
This is my code so far:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ifelse netlogo-web? [set max-turtles 300] [set max-turtles 300]
  create-healthy-cows Population-Size [ set shape "cow"
     set color lime
     set infected? false
     set disease? false
     ask n-of (random Population-Size) turtles [set gender-male? true]
     set size 3
     setxy random-xcor random-ycor
     set age random 200
     set label-color black ]
end
```

and also:

```
to check-reproduction
 ask turtles [if gender-male? = false [
    ask turtles [if any? turtles-here with [gender-male? = true]
      [reproduce-cows] ]]]
end


to reproduce-cows
  ask turtles [ if max-turtles < 300 [
  ask turtles [if age >= 50 [if (random-float 100 < Reproduction-Rate)
      [hatch 1
        [set color blue] ]]]]]
end
```

Also I have `gender-male?` set as a `turtles-own`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create random binary/boolean variable in Netlogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890224/how-to-create-random-binary-boolean-variable-in-netlogo)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`one-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/one-of.html) and see if you can come up with a solution. It's important to learn what you're doing and why, and not just ask for the answer, especially when its for a class assignment.

<sup>I've never seen or heard of NetLogo and it took me less than 5 minutes to come up with a solution and then find a second, better one.. Especially if this is an assignment you should be googling and researching instead of asking to be spoonfed!</sup>

Comment: Also don't have enough rep on SO to comment on OP question and/or mark as possible duplicate of [How to create random binary/boolean variable in Netlogo
](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28890224/6946577)